# Wifi won't stay up on BeagleBone

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, beagleboard

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a BeagleBone with an Edimax EW-7711UAn wifi adapter plugged into the USB port. I've configured /etc/network/interfaces and the wifi works, BUT:

1. The wlan0 interface doesn't always come up when booting the device. It comes up successfully about one in three attempts.
2. The interface sometimes goes down again, especially when not used for a while.

The /etc/network/interfaces file includes:

```
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-ssid "Bodoni"
    wpa-psk "<mypassword>"
```

In order to try to address point 1), I put the following in /etc/rc.local:

```
nohup sh -c "ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0"
```

But it hasn't seemed to help much. I'm guessing that the second problem might be connected with power management, so I might try turning that off in /etc/rc.local.

But does anyone have any thoughts on how I might get the wifi to come up reliably on boot? I'm running the BeagleBone headless with no Ethernet (it's on a robot) so it's important I get this fixed!

FYI, I'm using the default drivers - lsmod gives:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
aes_generic            27837  2 
arc4                    1111  2 
rt2800usb              12386  0 
rt2800lib              45146  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt               1457  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              10595  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              39077  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
mac80211              228509  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              167722  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
rfkill                 16703  1 cfg80211
binfmt_misc             6224  1 
spidev                  4620  0
```

I'm hoping not to have to compile a new driver because I haven't had much success with that!

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar problem with my BeagleBones using another wifi adapter using the rt2800usb driver.  Specifically I am using a DLINK DWA-125 (HW Rev A2) which is based on the rt3070 chip.

Same exact symptoms that you are reporting if I plug the DWA-125 directly into the USB port on the BeagleBone.

BUT if I plug the adapter into a USB extension cable and then plug the extension cable into the BeagleBone USB port, everything works fine.  I have done 100s of hours of Cloud9 development using this setup and no problems with Wifi whatsoever.

I am running the Angstrom distro - and I find the same issue on all three of last BB releases (4/22. 5/? and 6/18).

Length of USB extension cable doesn't seem to matter (at least between 1ft and 12ft - haven't tried anything below 1ft.)

I have 6 BeagleBones (4 ver A5 and 2 ver A6) - behavior is the same on all of these Beaglebones.

Also have 4 DWA-125 Rev A2 USB adapters - behavior is the same on all of these.

I have not experimented with other USB Wifi Adapters using the same or other chips/drivers.  And I haven't spent the time to track down the root cause of this behavior - I have code to write!

But, give it a try in case your experience matches mine - its a quick and easy 'fix'.

---- Addendum:

I just tried an experiment with the Belkin N150 Micro USB Wifi Adapter - based on the rtl8192cu chip and the standard drivers that come with the 6/18 BeagleBone Angstrom distribution.

Got very similar behavior:  The Wifi doesn't work at all when plugged directly into the USB port.  But when plugged in via a 1ft USB extension cable, everything works fine.

Comment: How very strange. At the moment I've got it working a little better. I put a bunch of commands in /etc/rc.local. If eth0 has no IP I use ifdown eth0, assuming we're running wireless, not wired. I then check to see if wlan0 has an IP. If not, I do ifdown wlan0 and then ifup --force wlan0. And for good measure, I release any DHCP lease and run dhclient to get a new one. So far, this has resulted in the wireless coming up fairly reliably & even staying up for long periods. I may write a cron job to do periodic checking & force the wireless up if it's not connected.

Comment: My situation was even worse - the USB port would go dead after attempting to use the a wifi dongle.  Only a reboot would bring it back.  A USB hub fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The best explanation i've found so far is [this one from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-wifi-with-beaglebone-black.pdf)

The main idea is that the Wifi dongle is destructed by the HDMI adapter, that is situated just under the USB slot. You have two workarounds in this case:

1. Put the Wifi-dongle as far as possible from the USB-slot by means of a cable
2. Disable the HDMI interface if you don't really need it!

Only the second option helped me.

Here are the steps:

```
> mkdir /mnt/boot
> mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/boot
> nano /mnt/boot/uEnv.txt

Remove the # in front of the cape_disable command

##Disable HDMI
cape_disable=capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

I hope it will help you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by removing the USB ESD spike protection IC (U10, TPD4S012). It should be wired between the USB connector and the CPU but it was placed after the USB connector on my board (rev. A4). I don't know if this is fixed on later revisions.

Update: this won't help much in some cases. Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/beaglebone/UPERscSdoEk) thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for most of a year until I googled long enough to find

wicd

After setting things up with wicd my 5 beaglebones have been rock solid on my home network on wifi dongles from the back bedroom to the garage. /etc/network/interfaces is not the way to go. I must have tried hundreds of configurations and some seemed to last for a day or two. I do remember the doc gave a good default for interfaces, very barebones. And wicd runs your supplicant if ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages to get reliable WiFi on the BeagleBone.  In the end, the answer was to use an Atheros dongle, since I had poor luck with RealTek and RALink chipsets.  The NetGear WNA1100 works very reliably for me, in both Angstrom and Ubuntu.  See my post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!category-topic/beagleboard/software/9KCIs7yqsa8).